# How to display data that was received on the Next.js client side in the browser page code

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

The problem is this. I don't understand at all how many sites using Next.js and others display information received (I assume) from a request to the server in the browser page code. To clarify the question, I will give an example.
Let's take GitHub as an example. If we look at the page code in the browser, we will see, for example, a nickname, which, I assume, is obtained by a request to the server. Question: how, without knowing who visited the site, did they send a request not on the client side, and received my profile? Even if you reload the page, you will not be able to see the loading process of the icon, nickname, mail and other information that is not stored in any way in any browser storage [GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yrAR.png).

How is this possible and how to implement it in Next.js? For example, in order to get data about a user who has visited the site so that he does not have to log in again, I send a request to the backend with the appropriate token and after a couple of seconds I receive all the necessary information. But at the same time, as React itself suggests, I first show the login and registration buttons, which were generated at the server build stage (don’t forget about SSR from Next.js), and only then, after receiving the data, the buttons are removed, and instead The user's avatar and nickname appear on them. I’ll repeat the question again: how can I skip the stage of buttons appearing and at the same time, information about the user is displayed in the browser page code for SEO (although in this example it’s a little pointless, but still)?

I combed through the documentation, many English-language sites and videos. But they cover simple examples that involve static data, i.e. requests for a list of products, for example. I don't need any additional information about anything to list it, so I can do it on the server. But to display information about users, I need to go into localStorage to check whether there is a token at all and whether it is valid.

Comment: I guess you are new to next js and SSR you should look at this video [link](https://youtu.be/O5cmLDVTgAs?si=RMcAerTeR-5z5mWy) this really helped me when I was starting with next js. I know it is a bit long but all your doubts will be cleared about user login, registration and SSR.